# Is it safe to repair and optimize mysql tables?

Tags: mysql

I use mysqltuner to tune the mysql server. It recommends to "Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance". I had done this on a single database before and I don't see any problem. Now, I have several client's databases on this server, I am hesitate to use optimize and repair on all databases. Is it safe to do this? Should I optimize their databases or ask them to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather leave it to customers if only for the reason `OPTIMIZE TABLE` **locks the table for the duration of the operation**.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had a problem with it.  I'd say it's about as safe as anything else in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely schedule this for a quiet/off-peak time, and do a database dump beforehand and immediately after, and compare if possible.

of course, you might want to consider whether there's a reason the DB performance is dropping off and look at the mysql slow query log to see if a new table layout would prevent problems happening.